# Can't get response from a request in a C socket (Linux)

Tags: c, linux

I have a C program that sends a HTTP request to an url, then retrieves the response, but I got a problem, its hanging forever on function `read`, modifying the REQUEST macro to an invalid HTTP request I can read the bad request response, but when I set a valid request it got stuck on `read` function, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define URL "www.google.com"

#define REQUEST "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n"

int main()
{
    struct addrinfo *info;
    
    if ( getaddrinfo(URL, "http", NULL, &info) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't retrieve info from url\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    memset(&client, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    
    if ( bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't bind the client\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        puts("client bound successfully");
    
    if ( connect(sfd, info->ai_addr, info->ai_addrlen) == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't connect to the server\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        puts("client connect successfully");
    
    if ( write(sfd, REQUEST, strlen(REQUEST)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't send request to server\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
        puts("request sent");
    
    puts("waiting response...\n");
    
    int chksize = 100;
    char buff[chksize];
    memset(buff, 0, chksize);
    
    // PROGRAM HANGS FOREVER HERE
    while ( read(sfd, buff, chksize - 1) > 0 )
    {
        printf("%s", buff);
        memset(buff, 0, chksize);
    }
    
    freeaddrinfo(info);
    close(sfd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's possible http for google redirects to https which might be less than 100 characters total. Try reading one byte as a time as a test

Comment: I've changed the value of chksize to 2, so read func will read 1 byte, it didn't work, I also tried replace "http" to "https" on getaddrinfo func and the behaviour have changed, it doesn't get stuck on read func, but also don't print any response.

Comment: Just for fun, print the value of `sfd` before the read to make sure it's a pointer. My wild guess is that it might be 0 and you're reading/writing from the stdin/stdout

Comment: the value of sfd before read is 3 ! how's that possible?

Comment: Actually, that makes sense. The socket is using file descriptor 3, which isn't stdin (0), stdout (1), or stderr (2)

Comment: Just for fun, change `== -1` to `!= 0` just in case someone has changed the return values

Comment: Wait. You need another newline when doing HTTP/1.1 to indicate you're done sending headers. I'm not sure that's the issue

Comment: I changed all == -1 to != 0, its all the same, I'll try add another line to the request as you said

Comment: I added another newline to request and it worked ! thanks

Comment: @BarryCarter apologize, when I wrote the answer I had not seen that this had been resolved in the comments.

Comment: @MadFred No worries. I openly encourage people to use my comments to create answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP 1 you have to end the request with an empty line.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP/1.1_request_messages

> Request syntax

> A client sends request messages to the server, which consist of:[48]

> a request line, consisting of the case-sensitive request method, a space, the requested URL, another space, the protocol version, a carriage return, and a line feed, e.g.:

```
GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1
```

> zero or more request header fields (at least 1 or more headers in case of HTTP/1.1), each consisting of the case-insensitive field name, a colon, optional leading whitespace, the field value, an optional trailing whitespace and ending with a carriage return and a line feed, e.g.:

```
Host: www.example.com
Accept-Language: en
```

> **an empty line**, consisting of a carriage return and a line feed;
> an optional message body.

> In the HTTP/1.1 protocol, all header fields except Host: hostname are optional.